# How Do I Click a div dropdown menu using VBA IE automation

Tags: vba, browser-automation

Have the following DIV class, where you click on the bottom it will create a drop down menu. In browser, you can click it with mouse, however with IE automation with VBA. I tried the ".click" method and doesn't work.
I also tried the FireEvent with "onclick" "onchange" "onmouseover" and nothing works. Trying to see if there is any other solution

```
<div id="add12" style="width: 47px; height: 23px; white-space: nowrap; 
position: static;" 
controltype="DropDown" param="par">
<input name="ct10115" id="ddl" type="hidden" value="E">
<input class="ffb-input" id="input" style="width: 13px;" maxlength="1" 
autocomplete="off">
<span class="ffb-arrow ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-Allui-button-text-icon-primary" id="teste2" role="button" ariadisabled="false" style="position: 
static;">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s" 
style="left: 0px; top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; position: static;"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text"></span>
</span>
<div class="ffb" id="example11" style="left: 0px; top: 29px; width: 450px; display: none; z- index: 21; opacity: 0.999;">
<div class="content" style="height: auto; max-height: 200px;" scrolltop="0">
  <div class="row" id="A" val="A" std_phase_cd="A" std_nm="A_">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 45px;">A </td>
          <td>none A </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="B" val="B" std__cd="B" std_nm="1">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 45px;">B </td>
          <td>none1 </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
 
  </div>
  <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the website publicly available? If yes then please share the URL and describe what button are you clicking.

Comment: Its not. so I post the HTML code from the website

Answer (score 0):

ok I got it figured out.
So I use the dev tool on browser, and found the event e.g. click, mousedown etc.

then I use IE.dipatchEvent to trigger the click event.